# How can I test a non-deterministic predicate in any order with PL-Unit?

Tags: unit-testing, prolog

- I want to **unit test a non-deterministic predicate** in Prolog with PL-Unit.
- I want to "assert" that the solutions I specify in my tests are ***the only*** solutions for the predicate.
- I'm **not concerned about the order** that each solution is specified in the test.

### What the SWI-Prolog manual says:

The SWI-Prolog manual has a great section called [testing non-deterministic predicates](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=testnondet)...

> 2.2.3 Testing non-deterministic predicates
>
> Non-deterministic predicates succeed zero or more times. Their results are tested either using findall/3 or setof/3 followed by a value-check or using the all or set options. The following are equivalent tests:

```
test(member) :-
        findall(X, member(X, [a,b,c]), Xs),
        Xs == [a,b,c].

test(member, all(X == [a,b,c])) :-
        member(X, [a,b,c]).
```

This is almost *exactly* what I need. However, for these tests to pass, the output has to be specified in the correct order: `[a, b, c]`. I'd like to be able to specify it in *any* order and still have the test pass.

### An example of what I'm trying:

Let's say I'm testing this (hypothetical) predicate that has two solutions.

```
specialNumber(X) :-
    X is 2;
    X is 4.
```

I could write a passing unit test like so...

```
% PASSES!
test(specialNumber, all(X == [2, 4])) :-
        specialNumber(X).
```

But it would fail if I swapped the order of the solutions...

```
% FAILS!
test(specialNumber, all(X == [4, 2])) :-
        specialNumber(X).
```

How can I make this test pass regardless of the order that the solutions are found?

Comment: Use `setof/3` to collect *and* sort, or use `findall/3` and then `sort/2`.

Comment: @mat Excellent idea. Would you have time to post an example? And would this only work for numeric lists?

Comment: Note: I still haven't been able to work it out. I don't understand how/where to use `setof/3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using **`setof/3`** instead of `findall/3` to collect and **sort** .

For example, given the slightly rewritten definition of your predicate:

```
special_number(X) :-
        (   X #= 2
        ;   X #= 4
        ).
```

We can define the following PlUnit test:

```
:- begin_tests(all).

test(solutions, Solutions = [2,4]) :-
        setof(X, special_number(X), Solutions).

:- end_tests(all).
```

This test case *continues* to work if you *rewrite* your predicate for example to:

```
special_number(X) :-
        (   X #= 4
        ;   X #= 2
        ).
```

In this case, we have:

```
?- findall(X, special_number(X), Ls).
Ls = [4, 2].

?- setof(X, special_number(X), Ls).
Ls = [2, 4].
```

As an alternative to `setof/3`, you can for example use:

- `findall/3`
- and then sort solutions manually with `sort/2`.

Related topics for you to read:

- **standard order of terms**
- `bagof/3`
- `(@<)/2`

I leave adding the necessary **libraries** and directives that are necessary to run the example above as an exercise.